# How to do customer login via mobile no and password REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have an issue while using end point of magento-2. I need to do the authentication using `mobile no and password` rather than email. I am explaining my code below.

```
$adminUrl1='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';
$ch1 = curl_init();
$data1 = array("username" => '9438835610', "password" => 'Abcdeg123@');

$data_string1 = json_encode($data1);                       
$ch1 = curl_init($adminUrl1); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string1);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string1))                                                                       
);       
$token1 = curl_exec($ch1);
$result = json_decode($token1, 1);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Here I need to login customer using Mobile no and password. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using mobile number you not get token.
For that follow below step.
Take 2 param 1) mobilenumner and pasword

1. Using mobile number to get user email address from custom api
2. Then call magento token api in pass user "email address" and "password"
   $adminUrl1='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';